# How should I do if I want to invoke a generic method with generic arguments?

Tags: java, generics, vector

In my book, there is not written how to invoke a generic method with generic arguments.
I have a method something like this.

```
public Vector<Double> VEKTOR( Vector <Double>num)
```

This method will return the vector's size. 
To get a result, I need my main invokes that method .. but I don't know how to invoke a generic method and generic arguments because my book did not explain that.. Is it the same like an usual method? I read some questions about that but they were difficult to understand(for lacking english.. and almost of them were talking about skills which I have never learnt)

Comment: Yo can read Java Oracle docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html

Comment: "_This method will return the vector's size_" - nope; it's a method called `VEKTOR` that returns a `Vector<Double>`.

Comment: Thanks to all who commented on this post. It was my first time to use <> as method's style(? Sorry I don't know English..) without any explanation from my book. That's why I thougth I should use some special tricks . But, now I know what to do! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yours is not a generic method; it is an ordinary method whose return is a specific realization of a generic type.  If it *were* a generic method then that might complicate things under some circumstances (i.e. when the method's type parameter(s) cannot be inferred), but usually invoking generic methods is substantially the same as invoking ordinary methods.

Furthermore, there are no special rules about invoking methods, ordinary or generic, having a return type or argument type that is a specific realization of a generic type.  The method must exist and be accessible.  The actual arguments must be assignment-compatible with the declared argument types, and the return value must be used in a manner consistent with its type, if it is used at all.  None of this is exciting or different.

In short, your book doesn't say anything about it because there isn't anything to say.

Example:

```
// ...
Vector<Double> argument = new Vector<>();
// ... maybe add some values ...
Vector<Double> result = VEKTOR(argument);
```

Comment: Aha thanks!! I just wondered that because I thought I should invoke this with some special (?) tricks. Thank you!